# Posts are invisible on the SE app

Tags: bug, android-app

On my android SE app the body of all posts is simply invisible. Look:

[image]

I wasn't even able to preview the question before posting.

Comment: Norepro. I can see everything fine.

Comment: @nicael I know that not everyone is having this issue. I need to know how to fix it.

Comment: might be compatibility issue.Even I have problems with the app!